# java script check box onto todo list

Tags: javascript, dom, checkbox, local-storage

how to modified todo list coding using java script DOM. Which mean to put check box into todo list coding. and save it after checked on local storage.

have making tutorial for java script to do coding for todo list. already done create DOM createElementById input checkbox. Unfortunetly checked sign lost after delete todo variable.

```
const checkbox = document.createElement('input'); 
checkbox.type = 'checkbox'; 
checkbox.id = todo.id; 
element.appendChild(checkbox);
```

Comment: please provide your relevant code snippets.

Comment: const checkbox = document.createElement('input');
checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
checkbox.id = todo.id;
element.appendChild(checkbox);

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: The code you show (which needs to be in the question, not in a comment) does not show the issue at all. Please update your question - [edit] it and then click the `[<>]` snippet editor and add RELEVANT HTML, CSS, Script and frameworks.
NOTE: SO does not support localStorage in a snippet so please comment those lines out

Comment: You forgot todo `checkbox.value = todo.value; checkbox.name = todo.name;`

Answer (score 0):

One, you're missing the fact that two tags cannot have the same `id`. but I think that here, it's going to be okay. The `value` needs to be copied over, too.

Try this with [PipesJS + Modala](https://github.com/wise-penny/pipes)

That will insert, onclick, to the "value" attribute "true".

```
{
  "tagname": "dyn",
  "class": "set-attr"
  "set-attr": "value",
  "ajax": "checkbox.php",
  "insert": "idOfCheckBox",
  {
   "tagname": "div",
   "id": "idOfCheckBox"
  }
}
```

Use the `<carousel></carousel>` tag but add the class "carousel-auto-off"

As I said, they each need a different `id`

if you want, then make a json, based like the one above that has a form name in its `classList`. Then use `form-class` as a attribute from your submit button, which can be `<dyn></dyn>` tag, which has your value from `form-name` in the `classList`. They'll be carried to the form-handling page based on `name` and `value`.

```
<dyn id="checkbox-submit" form-class="your-form-name">Click here to submit</dyn>

<input id="checkers" name="checkers" type="checkbox" ajax="above.json" class="modala your-form-name">Insertion of JSON in HTML (even just text)</input>
```

any questions, ask.